# Have my own chrome:// or file:// point different places

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Currently I have a webserver hosted locally with a bunch of different data that I need for work I want to start a project where I can put foo://bar and it would pull up from category foo and any results from bar. I have the search functionality just was wondering if it was possible to have custom flags like that within Chrome/Edge.

Comment: You'll have to modify the source code of Chromium and compile it.

Comment: I agree with wOxxOm's comment. You can also refer to [this article](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/how_to_add_your_feature_flag.md) about adding a new feature flag in chrome. You can see that it needs to edit the browser's source code.